# Is this a real Concorde or just a replica?

Tags: road-bike, frames, fork, vintage

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm confused with this, the lugs in this bike look identical with another Concorde but the tubing sticker clearly says "Reynolds". (Concorde only uses Colombus, right?)

Comment: Is the reynolds sticker on top of the clear coat or under the clear coat?   IE can you feel the edge of it with your finger nail?  The logo looks right on the downtube.

Comment: Searching suggests that Concorde is a Dutch brand who definitely used colombus but there were some vague mentions of a Canadian version from CCM which used the same name and was made from Reynolds tube.  However googling "CCM Concorde" shows quite a different logo.   Puzzling.   Could it have been repainted with the wrong logo/sticker?

Answer (score -1):

I have a 1990s Concorde Americas that has Tange tubing. I bought it when it was just a couple of years old.

Comment: congratulations on your bike. How does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: Please brows our [tour] to learn how the site works. You've made the common error of assuming this is a chat forum, whereas SE is a Q&A forum.  Your answer doesn't attempt to answer the question.  Could you please use EDIT to tell the Original Poster if their pictures resemble your one at all?  That would increase the relevancy.

Comment: OP asked if Concorde exclusively used Columbus tube sets, evidence of a bike built with a Tange tube set speaks to that.